# CUDA NPP - image reduction - find sum/average of all image pixels

Tags: c++, cuda, npp

I have an 8-bit unsigned char image, which is grayscale (values between 0-255), and I want to use the NPP CUDA library documentation, which provides some functions such as `nppiSum_8u64s_C1R`, to find the sum and average over all the pixels.

But, I don't know what `oSizeROI` stands for in the `nppiSum_8u64s_C1R` function? Should I just input my image dimensions `w256 x h1024` here?

image_statistics__functions.html#gad5ca4eb684d5414e6026564ea63a1437">http://graphics.im.ntu.edu.tw/~bossliaw/nvCuda_doxygen/html/group_*image*_statistics__functions.html#gad5ca4eb684d5414e6026564ea63a1437

Comment: Yes, `oSizeROI` is the size of the input image.

Comment: @sgar91: Want to add that as a short answer? I'll upvote it to get this off the unanswered list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the NPP function `nppiSum_8u64s_C1R`, the argument `oSizeROI` is the size (in pixels) of the input image. So yes, you should just input the image dimensions here.